# Creating a 3 column html table from arraylist?

Tags: java, html, jsp

How can I create a 3 column table in HTML from an `ArrayList`?

My current code looks like this:

```
<table border="0">

        <%
            for (int i = 1; i < states.size(); i++) {
        %>
        <TR>
            <%
                for (int col = 1; col <= 3; col++) {
            %>
            <TD>
                <%
                    out.println(states.get(i));}
                %>
            </TD>
            
        </TR>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </table>
```

I get a 3 column format table but 3x the same entry in each row...
[image]

### Expected output

```
Albania | Algeria   | American Samoa
Andorra | Angola    | Anguilla
..
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What are you trying to put in the other columns?

Comment: All the columns & rows should be filled with different state/countries.

Comment: So is there another variable that stores countries? It looks like there is an array of states, but I do not see an array of countries. Did you want to format each cell with something like California/USA?

Comment: Sorry, I should be more precise...
I have just 1 array with states which I want to display in a 3column table
No countries ;)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Sorry, i'm a bit confused, would you be able to provide an example of what you want? For instance, what is in the first row, second row, etc.

Comment: @DavidZ.  Good question.  I have added some output at the end that shows (what **I think** is) the **Expected output** but we should not take it seriously until the OP confirms that is their meaning.  An SSCCE of current code, would also be handy.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew! This is exactly the output I want!
It's my first time on stackoverflow, so I have currently no idea of SSCCE, but I will give it a try!

Comment: BTW - those 'states' in your output are actually 'countries'.

Comment: My followup question is what does the ArrayList look like.  Is it just ["Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", ...]?

Comment: Sounds great, it looks like that Michael has the right answer for you below. Also for the outer array, you need to only go to states.size()/3 instead of states.size(). For the inner array, you need to do a check to ensure that you do not exceed the size of your array.

Comment: right, each country has it's own index. Like your example! Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the requirement correctly (not sure that is the case), then something like this will give you a start.

```
<table border="0">
    <tr>
    <%
        for (int i = 1; i < states.size(); i++) {
            out.println("<td>" + states.get(i) + "</td>");
            if (i>0 && i%3==0) {
                out.println("</tr><tr>");
            }
        }
    %>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It will produce output something along these lines..

```
Albania | Algeria   | American Samoa
Andorra | Angola    | Anguilla
..
```

Note that it still has problems.  If there are 'multiples of 3' countries, there will be an entirely empty line at the end of the table.  If not, the last row will not have the correct number of columns.  BNI.

Comment: You're welcome. :) BTW - are you ***certain*** that the very first country is listed?  I suspect `int i = 1` should be `int i = 0`

Comment: haha :D i recognized it! But now I have a 4th column just for one country Oo

Answer (score 0):

It's just a small typo.  You're indexing with 'i', but your internal variable is col.

Change it to:

```
...
out.println(states.get(3*col + i));
...
```

Try that one, you might need to zero index your column now.

Comment: now the table looks like this:

Col1   Col2    Col3

Alaska Arizona Arkansas
Alaska Arizona Arkansas
Alaska Arizona Arkansas
Alaska Arizona Arkansas
Alaska Arizona Arkansas

:/

Comment: Ohh, I get it now.  You have one array and you want to index it like a 3x(size/3) table.  Ok...

Answer (score 0):

Note :

- Index in List start with 0
- You need to compute the index before you retrieve.

  ```
      <%
          for (int i = 0; i < states.size(); i++) {
      %>
      <TR>
          <%
              for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
          %>
          <TD>
              <%  
                  int index= (i*3)+col;
                  if(states.size()>index+1)
                  {    
                   out.println(states.get(index));
                  }
                  i = i+1;  
              %>
          </TD>

      </TR>
      <%
          }
      %>
  </table>
  ```

Comment: made a silly mistake. I have edited the answer. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this.. Just add another variable which will be used when retrieving info from your array list.

```
<table border="0">

    <%

        for (int i = 1, index = 0; i < states.size(); i++) {
    %>
    <TR>
        <%
            for (int col = 1; col <= 3; col++) {
        %>
        <TD>
            <%
                out.println(states.get(index++));}
            %>
        </TD>

    </TR>
    <%
        }
    %>
</table>
```